# Why is my masonary line of code not working?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am a starting junior developer who is relatively new to coding.

I have been assigned a task of creating a pop up modal box to replace an old drop down menu.

I have created the pop up modal box but when I place the masonry layout into my new piece of code it doesn't work.

```js
var content = "";

$('a[href="#ex5"]').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).modal({
    escapeClose: false,
    clickClose: false,
    showClose: false,
  });
  $('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', false);
});
var masonary_layout = '';
var offset = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.ads-section .sectors .options .single-option .sector-print-temp').change(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      $('.sector-print').val('1');
    } else {
      $('.sector-print').val('0');
    }
    offset = 0;
    setOffsetValue();
    loadAds();
    //$('.load-more').hide();
  });
});
```

```css
.onlyThese {
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

input[type="checkbox"]+label {
  color: white
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label {
  color: red
}


}
input:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<!-- Remember to include jQuery :) -->

<!-- jQuery Modal -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.css" />





<div class="sectors">
  <div style="padding-top:20px" ;>

    <a class="btn" href="#ex5">
     
     Sectors <span class="down-arrow"; style="color:blue"> 
     <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i> 
     </span> 
     </div></a>

  </div>
</div>

<div id="ex5" ; class="modal" ; style="background-color:black;">



  <div class="options" ; style="line-height:1.8; float:left;">
    <p> <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="group1" class="sector-print-temp">
      <label for="group1" class="onlyThese">
<b> Publication </b> </label> </p>

  </div>


  <div class="your-div">
    <p style="font-size:16px; text-transform:uppercase; float:right">
      <a href="#" rel="modal:close" ; class="onlyThese" style="color:white"> <b>Apply</b></a>
    </p>
  </div>

</div>
```

I would just like clarification on what I am doing wrong.

Comment: I can recommend formatting your code. Not just "in this post", but in general. Install a modern formatter like [prettier](https://prettier.io/) in your editor, and use it liberally. On that note, can you please format the code in your question? That makes it _much_ easier for people to read through, and as such far more likely they won't ignore the question.

Comment: I don't see any masonary code here. Only thing I see in code is masonary_layout=''; Not sure what you are trying to do. What is not working?

Comment: Will do @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans

Comment: The masonary_layout="; is not working? @NawedKhan

Comment: Could you possibly define what do you mean by "doesn't work"? Console output? Got an error? Browser crashed? Something fell apart?

Comment: Do you mean that adding the empty `var masonry_layout = '';` breaks your working code? As @i100 asked, are their errors in your browser's console?

Comment: No console error; but that line of code loads up images from the database but it doesn't anymore.  @i100

Comment: @OmegaBlastoise please format _all_ the code. Your HTML is still all over the place, and contains illegal characters (why are there semicolons inside your HTML tags? O_o) and your CSS has a `}` too many.

Comment: It seems you do not understand much that code, do you? I pasted all three parts in jsbin.com, and they seem to work fine. Add this -   console.log('masonary_layout: '  + masonary_layout); - into both of your functions, open console and watch there. Neither click nor ready change the variable contents. If it is filled "from database" as you said the problem is not in the quoted code. Either server-side or DB query do not filter result correctly.

Comment: Yeah I figured my problem would be from the DB side of things. Thanks, @i100